# Command terminated by signal 11

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

Изучаю ассемблер.

**main.asm:**

```
global _start
_start:
section .bss
    number:    resd    1 ; reserve the partition 
section .text 
    main:      mov     ebx, 12 ; set the number to the register ebx
               mov     [number], ebx ; set the number from ebx to partition
```

Возвращает мне **ошибку:**

```
Command terminated by signal 11
```

Comment: У вас код сам никак не завершает свое выполнение. После него в памяти будет мусор, и дальше операционная система принудительно завершит выполнение кода при попытке выполнить недопустимую операцию.

Comment: Что надо сделать для этого?

Comment: Посмотреть полный пример Hello World под вашу операционную систему, и написать код на его основе.